# Lambda with if condition in map()

Tags: python, lambda

I have this bit of a practice code:

```
even = []
odd = []

for x in range(1000):
    if x % 2 != 0:
        odd.append(x)
    else:
        even.append(x)

print map(lambda x: x if str(x)[-1] == '2' else pass, even)

print even
print odd
```

In my mind, I should get in the end full list of odd numbers in 0 - 999 range and a list of even numbers from the same range which do not end with "2". In practice however, I keep on getting syntax error pointing to the "pass" in lambda expression.

What am I doing wrong here?

Cheers,
Greem

Comment: You're doing extra work by making a string. Try `x % 10 == 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pass` is a statement, but inline `if`, being an operator, needs its operands to be expressions. `map` can’t actually remove elements from the sequence, but [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) (returns a new list with only the values for which the function returns `True`) can:

```
print filter(lambda x: str(x)[-1] == '2', even)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and don't like filters and lambda, you can accomplish this with Python [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php):

```
print [x for x in even if str(x)[-1] == '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
even = []
odd = []

for x in range(1000):
    if x % 2 != 0:
        odd.append(x)
    else:
        even.append(x)

print (filter(lambda x: str(x)[-1] == '2', even))

print (even)
print (odd)
```

Will work on python 3 too..